# Magento 2.1:- Can set all shipping method programmatically?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, model, plugin

I create one module in `Magento 2.1`.

I want to need set `all shipping method programmatically` using custom module with `plugin` or `model`.

Can it possible for that ?
And yes, so how it possible ?

Any one know give me suggestion for that.

Thanks for answer in advance.

Comment: "all shipping method programmatically" is for only one address or multi address?

Comment: For both @KhoaTruongDinh